# Java connection to Splunk Cloud error

Tags: java, splunk

I'm trying to connect to Splunk through a Java 8 application. While making a connection to Splunk Cloud, I'm getting the below error at this line:

```
HttpService.setSslSecurityProtocol(SSLSecurityProtocol.TLSv1_2)
```

Error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.splunk.SSLSecurityProtocol.(Ljava/lang/String;ILcom/splunk/SSLSecurityProtocol;)V
>           at com.splunk.SSLSecurityProtocol$2.(SSLSecurityProtocol.java:7) ~[splunk-1.6.2.0.jar!/:1.6.2]
>           at com.splunk.SSLSecurityProtocol.(SSLSecurityProtocol.java:7) ~[splunk-1.6.2.0.jar!/:1.6.2]

Can any one provide the solution?

Comment: Did you get the [JCE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)?

Comment: @kartik use the "edit" button.

Comment: Yes I have used JCE. Still issue exists.

Comment: any one with solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is issue with splunk version 1.6.2.0. Use the latest version of splunk. 
I fixed this issue by using 1.6.3.0.